# Why do we have $H_2(\mathbb P^1) \cong H_1(\mathbb A^1\setminus \{0\})$?

Tags: etale-cohomology

This question comes from Matt E's answer in

[What is the intuition behind the concept of Tate twists?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/57750/what-is-the-intuition-behind-the-concept-of-tate-twists/57757#)

He remarks that $H_2(\mathbb P^1) \cong H_1(\mathbb A^1\setminus \{0\})$, but I don't see where this comes from. Could someone give more detail?